# document snapshot querying issue

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Hi, can I know why there is error below document and how I can resolve it?

Comment: I know it's a different class, how can I do it in such a way that I can access the document

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not provide pictures of code and text.  Copy the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: alright thanks i will take note of it

Answer (score 0):

You can access document inside **_EventAdminEditState** using **widget.document['Key']**. It's better to initialize these variables inside **initState**.

Comment: package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart

The current configuration.

A [State] object's configuration is the corresponding [StatefulWidget] instance. This property is initialized by the framework before calling [initState]. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new widget with the same [runtimeType] and [Widget.key] as the current configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the new widget and then call [didUpdateWidget], passing the old configuration as an argument.

Got this error.

Comment: Have you placed these initializations inside initState?

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    final String details = document['Details'];
    final String eventTime = document['EventTime'];
    final String location = document['Location'];
    final String imageURL = document['Image'];
    final String registrationInstructions = document['RegisterInstructions'];
    
  } *This is what I have written*

Comment: Can u please provide complete code, of which you have placed screenshot?